# Can I aggregate database data based on multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I want to find data in a row that is aggregated on attributes from more than one column.  That probably sounds like a bunch of gibberish, so I'll give you an example...here's a database table with three columns:

```
GroupingId     Type           Date
1              NULL           1/1/11
1              NULL           2/2/22
2              NULL           1/1/11
2              A              2/2/22
3              A              1/1/11
3              B              2/2/22
4              A              1/1/11
4              NULL           2/2/22
```

I'd like to do a SELECT, and GROUP BY the GroupingId.  That's easy enough.

But for the other two columns I want something that is really dependant on both columns.  If I just wanted the MAX Date for any given group, that would be simple.  What I really want is the Type to prefer NOT NULL, while the Date should be MAX...but I want them to always be from the same row (with the Type value being NOT NULL taking precedence).

So my results should be something like

```
1       NULL      2/2/22       // both Types are null, so last date chosen
2       A         2/2/22       // one Type not null, so that date chosen
3       B         2/2/22       // both Types not null, so last date chosen
4       A         1/1/11       // one Type not null, so that date chosen (and it is not the most recent date)
```

If I do a MAX on Date, that's not right.  If I do a COALESCE on Type, I'll get a non-null value over a NULL...but not necessarily the most recent one.

Is there a clean way to do this?  I think I see how I can do this with a series selects, a table variable, and a UNION, which is how I am going to try to move forward, but if there's a clean SQL solution that someone could just even make a nod at, that would be welcome.

I'm in SQL Server, but I'm guessing that if there's a clean SQL way to do it, it will probably be fairly DB agnostic.

Comment: There are some notable differences between, for example, SQL Server and MySQL, in how group by works, so I've applied a db-specific tag.

Comment: @Mellamokb Fair enough.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like such?

```
;WITH CTESample (GroupingId, Type, Date) AS
(
    SELECT 1, NULL, '1/1/11'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, NULL, '2/2/22'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, NULL, '1/1/11'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'A', '2/2/22'     UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'A', '1/1/11'     UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'B', '2/2/22'     UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'A', '1/1/11'     UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, NULL, '2/2/22'    
)
,Partitioned AS
(
    SELECT *
            ,rNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupingID ORDER BY Type DESC, Date DESC)
    FROM CTESample
)
SELECT *
FROM Partitioned
WHERE rNum = 1
```

Comment: Thanks!  This nailed it.  And now I know some new SQL!

Answer (score 1):

This is a candidate for using `Rank()`.

So, I'm just way too slow... Don't tell my boss.

An example anyhow:

```
SELECT
  [sub].[GroupingID],
  [sub].[Type],
  [sub].[Date]
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    [GroupingID],
    [Type],
    [Date],
    Rank() OVER(PARTITION BY [GroupingID] ORDER BY (CASE WHEN [Type] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) DESC, [Date] DESC, [Type] ASC) AS [Rank]
  FROM [Data]
) AS [sub]
WHERE [sub].[Rank] = 1
ORDER BY [GroupingID] ASC
```

Comment: This is a candidate for being a comment.

Comment: Definitely, but I can't Fiddle up an example that fast! Working on it!

Comment: @mellamokb - this is a candidate for being an early answered timestamp

Comment: @Hogan: Indeed.. tsk. tsk. :)